# Вылетает приложение на андроид после установки admob

Tags: android, unity3d, admob

Ребят, помогите решить проблему.
Имеется новый 3д проект в Unity, в котором есть 2 кнопки. Первая кнопка ничего не делает, а вторая это выход с приложения.
Устанавливаю плагин AdMob по инструкции.. После чего билд проекта сразу на телефон.
В результате при автозапуске приложения на телефоне сразу вылет с ошибкой - сбой работы. и так при каждой попытке запустить приложение.
Поиск в гугле ничего не дал, т.к. в основном проблемы связанные с отсутствием(показом) рекламы..
UPD LogCat лог при запуске приложения

```
0001.01.01 00:00:00.000 -1 -1 Info  --------- beginning of main
2020.10.15 17:31:48.584 22836 22836 Error Zygote isWhitelistProcess - Process is Whitelisted
2020.10.15 17:31:48.586 22836 22836 Error Zygote accessInfo : 1
2020.10.15 17:31:48.639 22836 22836 Error ltCompany.test Not starting debugger since process cannot load the jdwp agent.
2020.10.15 17:31:48.780 22836 22836 Info ltCompany.test The ClassLoaderContext is a special shared library.
2020.10.15 17:31:48.802 22836 22836 Debug AndroidRuntime Shutting down VM
0001.01.01 00:00:00.000 -1 -1 Info  --------- beginning of crash
2020.10.15 17:31:48.804 22836 22836 Error AndroidRuntime FATAL EXCEPTION: main
2020.10.15 17:31:48.804 22836 22836 Error AndroidRuntime Process: com.DefaultCompany.test2, PID: 22836
2020.10.15 17:31:48.804 22836 22836 Error AndroidRuntime java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to get provider com.google.android.gms.ads.MobileAdsInitProvider: java.lang.IllegalStateException: 
2020.10.15 17:31:48.804 22836 22836 Error AndroidRuntime 
2020.10.15 17:31:48.804 22836 22836 Error AndroidRuntime ******************************************************************************
2020.10.15 17:31:48.804 22836 22836 Error AndroidRuntime * Invalid application ID. Follow instructions here:                          *
2020.10.15 17:31:48.804 22836 22836 Error AndroidRuntime * https://googlemobileadssdk.page.link/admob-android-update-manifest         *
2020.10.15 17:31:48.804 22836 22836 Error AndroidRuntime * to find your app ID.                                                       *
2020.10.15 17:31:48.804 22836 22836 Error AndroidRuntime ******************************************************************************
2020.10.15 17:31:48.804 22836 22836 Error AndroidRuntime 
2020.10.15 17:31:48.804 22836 22836 Error AndroidRuntime 
2020.10.15 17:31:48.804 22836 22836 Error AndroidRuntime    at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:6880)
2020.10.15 17:31:48.804 22836 22836 Error AndroidRuntime    at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:6422)
2020.10.15 17:31:48.804 22836 22836 Error AndroidRuntime    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:6326)
2020.10.15 17:31:48.804 22836 22836 Error AndroidRuntime    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1300(ActivityThread.java:242)
2020.10.15 17:31:48.804 22836 22836 Error AndroidRuntime    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1821)
2020.10.15 17:31:48.804 22836 22836 Error AndroidRuntime    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
2020.10.15 17:31:48.804 22836 22836 Error AndroidRuntime    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:216)
2020.10.15 17:31:48.804 22836 22836 Error AndroidRuntime    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7211)
2020.10.15 17:31:48.804 22836 22836 Error AndroidRuntime    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
2020.10.15 17:31:48.804 22836 22836 Error AndroidRuntime    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:494)
2020.10.15 17:31:48.804 22836 22836 Error AndroidRuntime    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:975)
2020.10.15 17:31:48.804 22836 22836 Error AndroidRuntime Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: 
2020.10.15 17:31:48.804 22836 22836 Error AndroidRuntime 
2020.10.15 17:31:48.804 22836 22836 Error AndroidRuntime ******************************************************************************
2020.10.15 17:31:48.804 22836 22836 Error AndroidRuntime * Invalid application ID. Follow instructions here:                          *
2020.10.15 17:31:48.804 22836 22836 Error AndroidRuntime * https://googlemobileadssdk.page.link/admob-android-update-manifest         *
2020.10.15 17:31:48.804 22836 22836 Error AndroidRuntime * to find your app ID.                                                       *
2020.10.15 17:31:48.804 22836 22836 Error AndroidRuntime ******************************************************************************
2020.10.15 17:31:48.804 22836 22836 Error AndroidRuntime 
2020.10.15 17:31:48.804 22836 22836 Error AndroidRuntime 
2020.10.15 17:31:48.804 22836 22836 Error AndroidRuntime    at com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzza.attachInfo(com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads-lite@@19.3.0:24)
2020.10.15 17:31:48.804 22836 22836 Error AndroidRuntime    at com.google.android.gms.ads.MobileAdsInitProvider.attachInfo(com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads-lite@@19.3.0:3)
2020.10.15 17:31:48.804 22836 22836 Error AndroidRuntime    at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:6875)
2020.10.15 17:31:48.804 22836 22836 Error AndroidRuntime    ... 10 more
2020.10.15 17:32:04.289 22836 22853 Info ltCompany.test Explicit concurrent copying GC freed 9(22KB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 33% free, 1006KB/1518KB, paused 166us total 17.276ms
2020.10.15 17:32:04.814 22836 22853 Info ltCompany.test Explicit concurrent copying GC freed 3707(143KB) AllocSpace objects, 1(20KB) LOS objects, 33% free, 1007KB/1519KB, paused 177us total 17.486ms
2020.10.15 17:32:05.343 22836 22853 Info ltCompany.test Explicit concurrent copying GC freed 3714(143KB) AllocSpace objects, 1(20KB) LOS objects, 33% free, 1007KB/1519KB, paused 175us total 17.562ms
2020.10.15 17:32:05.843 22836 22853 Info ltCompany.test Explicit concurrent copying GC freed 3711(144KB) AllocSpace objects, 1(20KB) LOS objects, 33% free, 1007KB/1519KB, paused 170us total 17.264ms
2020.10.15 17:32:06.368 22836 22853 Info ltCompany.test Explicit concurrent copying GC freed 3709(144KB) AllocSpace objects, 1(20KB) LOS objects, 33% free, 1007KB/1519KB, paused 194us total 18.883ms
2020.10.15 17:32:06.889 22836 22853 Info ltCompany.test Explicit concurrent copying GC freed 3713(144KB) AllocSpace objects, 1(20KB) LOS objects, 33% free, 1007KB/1519KB, paused 177us total 17.531ms
2020.10.15 17:32:07.415 22836 22853 Info ltCompany.test Explicit concurrent
```

Comment: Без логов ошибки вам помочь невозможно, т.к. надо будет перечислять тысячи (серьёзно тысячи, без сарказма) возможных причин ошибки, что займет часы, а скорее даже дни.

Comment: какой лог нужен? точнее откуда, где взять?

Comment: Как это в Unity сделать - не знаю. Попробуйте вот эту доку посмотреть: https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.mobile.android-logcat@0.1/manual/index.html Ну и/или поставить AndroidStudio, запустить приложение и там смотреть в LogCat. Но тут, конечно, может быть много нюансов. Однако стоит изучить это, т.к. без умения смотреть логи программы вы дальше HelloWorld вряд ли продвинетесь.

Comment: А, вижу, лог получилось достать) Вот в нём написано, что у вас что-то не то с ID приложения. Посмотрите что предлагают по ссылке из сообщения об ошибке и проверьте настройки рекламы в проекте - возможно вы где-то используете тестовый ID или неправильный или вообще забыли его указать.

Comment: Если самомстоятельно не получится найти проблему - выложите настройки рекламы (хотя бы и в виде скринов) в проекте и в консоли поставщика рекламы. ОБЯЗАТЕЛЬНО СКРЫВ ID приложения и баннеров, иначе они утекут в сеть. Возможно что-то можно будет сказать.

Comment: Как оказалось это моя невнимательность.. Не совсем с нужного места скопировал ID приложения. Благодарю за помощь)

Answer (score 1):

в логах есть инструкция - как исправить ид https://googlemobileadssdk.page.link/admob-android-update-manifest